# MySQL-python is not supported in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, macos, mysql-python

How could install mysql-python in python 3 using MacOS?

I tried this too:

```
$ brew install mysql

$ pip install mysqlclient
```

and it returned me the following error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kz/hw6d2_6j2xbgr4vs3c38zm040000gn/T/pip-install-_pr7g788/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kz/hw6d2_6j2xbgr4vs3c38zm040000gn/T/pip-install-_pr7g788/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/kz/hw6d2_6j2xbgr4vs3c38zm040000gn/T/pip-record-caw5qeb2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/mysqlclient
         cwd: /private/var/folders/kz/hw6d2_6j2xbgr4vs3c38zm040000gn/T/pip-install-_pr7g788/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/include/mysql -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/kz/hw6d2_6j2xbgr4vs3c38zm040000gn/T/pip-install-_pr7g788/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/kz/hw6d2_6j2xbgr4vs3c38zm040000gn/T/pip-install-_pr7g788/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/kz/hw6d2_6j2xbgr4vs3c38zm040000gn/T/pip-record-caw5qeb2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

the next try I use pip instaed of brew, but keep returning error.

```
$ pip install mysql
```

[image]

Any idea about how I can install `mysql-python` package or someone similar to use `MySQLdb` module if it's possible?

Comment: Try `pip install mysql`

Comment: I tried. In my post you have the error too

Comment: @JesusHedo What is the output of `which pip`? What about `which pip3`?

Comment: happens the same

Comment: the output you have it in the post

Comment: @JesusHedo I mean the command `which pip` and `which pip3`. Please add that to your post.

Comment: Have you tried with pymysql: `pip install pymysql `?